# Angularjs button ngClass not applied correctly on click

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a button using bootstrap button classes "btn btn-default btn-primary btn-xs". An "active" class that contains "background:red;" is added only when a scope variable "isactive" evaluates to true using "ngClass" within the template like the following:

```
ng-class="{'active': isactive == true}"
```

I add a click event to the button (ng-click) that once clicked, sets isactive to true.

I notice that when I click the `<button>`, nothing changes until I click anywhere else on the page, which causes the button to change the color fine.

Oddly, when I click the button and do not click elsewhere, instead when I right click, the button does turn red for a few, but then back to blue. When I inspect the element, it appears the "active" class is applied/added to the set of existing bootstrap classes for buttons. In my CSS, I have the following:

```
.active {
background:red;
}

.active:active {
background:red;
}
```

What is the issue? Does this have anything to do with bootstrap button classes?

Comment: Have tried just "{'active': isactive}" ?

Comment: Yes, I had that first.. oddly enough the same behavior occurred, so I added the == true just to see if it would make a difference, which it didnt.

Comment: Would you be able to post some code that replicates your issue? For starters: http://jsfiddle.net/FMUPz/

Comment: There might be other stronger rules that also set the background. Try adding `!important` like this `background: red !important;` first. If it works you have to make your rule to become the strongest.

Comment: @runTarm THANK YOU. Post your comment as an answer? I don't know what bootstrap css is causing this behavior, but it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be other rules that also set the background and they are also stronger than yours.

Try adding an `!important` flag like this first:

```
background: red !important;
```

If it works you should make your rule somehow to become stronger than others that set the background.